# on.('click) for dynamically created element is getting called on execution time without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a simple quiz kind of page. So I created grid with  element.

Here is the div which has the grid cloned.

```
Var template = $(".answer-layout-").clone();
```

And the listener for the element in loop is

```
$("a", template ).click(this.Answer_PickOne_OnClick(item));
```

The function implementation is,

```
this.Answer_PickOne_OnClick = function (sender, e) {}
```

I expect the click action to get trigger when i click the clement. But it is getting triggered on execution of the code.

Tried many ways by passing  argument and so but fails. Any suggestion please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because code `this.Answer_PickOne_OnClick(item)` actually executes your function. If you want to hook it as event handler instead, you should wrap in in a function:

```
$("a", template ).click(function() {
    this.Answer_PickOne_OnClick(item);
});
```

Comment: Saved my day ! Simple and powerful solution. Thanks.